# How can I scroll to the bottom of the div when it is being re-opened Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular

**Problem:** I have a chat, and I need it to always scroll to the bottom like a typical chat, unless the user chooses to scroll up. If the chat is minimized and re-opened, I need it to open at the bottom of the chat, and not the top.

I've looked through a bunch of different suggestions and tried them, and I have the majority of my solution working. The below is the Solution I am using, so that my chat is always scrolling to the bottom, every time someone types a new message. It works great!

However, I still can't get it to scroll to the bottom, if they minimize and then reopen the chat. When they minimize, and it hides, and then they re-open that div, it always is at the top of the chat. So it's not showing the latest conversation. If they type something, it will go to the bottom as expected since I am subscribed to the messages, but it won't start at the bottom. Anyone have this issue and resolve it?

I would really like to just be able to call `this.scrollToBottom()` whenever they click to re-open the chat, but for some reason that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 @ViewChildren('messages') messages: QueryList<any>;
 @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.messages.changes.subscribe(this.scrollToBottom);
  }


scrollToBottom = () => {
    try {
      this.content.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.content.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch (err) { }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="chat-box" #content>
    <div #messages *ngFor="let conversation of wholeConversation">
  // lots of stuff to do with chat
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `scrollToBottom` right after all your chats have loaded or whenever you want the scroll behaviour.

Comment: That's what I tried, but that function isn't doing anything. It is being called, but it isn't scrolling down unless something is typed.

Answer (score 0):

add the following in your component file.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
 this.scrollToBottom
}
```

Comment: Not a good technique because all chat may not have been loaded in ngOnInit()

Comment: So the div the chat is in is only part of the page, it's a chat over to the bottom right. It's the only thing I want to scroll down, the main page should stay normal.

Comment: can you please share your html snippet?

Comment: <div class="chat-box" #content>
    <div #messages *ngFor="let conversation of wholeConversation">
  // lots of stuff to do with chat
   </div>
</div>

Comment: I added it to the original question so it's formatted easier to read.

Comment: try calling the scrolltobottom method by binding it with hostListener. add the following in your ts file                                                   @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
 this.scrollToBottom
}

Comment: edited the snippet with my new answer, please try and let me know

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. Would I call onResize when they reopen the chat?

Comment: if possible can you please add the code in stackblitz?